# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter

Tags: c#, json, exception, json.net

I receive this exception during parsing string containing JSON:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path '[114].var2', line 1, position 431602.
```

So I went to exactly that (431602) position and found that it's here:
(...)lZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqK**jp**KWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW1(...)

So it's just simply "jp" chars which shouldn't be anything wrong.

What could be a reason for this exception?

EDIT
To be more specific I also put a whole string with few variables around it:

```
"var1":"946","var2":"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","var3":"77241"
```

Comment: I assume those "(...)" mean that string is much longer than you showed us?

Comment: @Mosquito Yes, it's much longer but I found no reason to put it all here.

Comment: The input which you have given does not appear to be in JSON format ? It would be more helpful if you can share the exact string you are trying to parse.

Comment: @prthrokz I edited my question, I hope it will helps.

Comment: Hmm its weird that it says expected delimiter at 431602, however i find the length of var2's value to be 3339. Can you please tell which method is throwing the exception ? If you are reading the JSON into a buffer, make sure it is large enough

Comment: This works for me, though I assume you escape all characters correctly and put {} around the input string? Also, do you deserialize it into a specific type, and if so, what type is var2 of?

Comment: @ChristianGenne the problem is that I don't need this var2 and my class which I use for storing data from parsed JSON doesn't have this variable specified, so it should ignore it. Though it complains all the time. Yes, bracers are around the string.

Comment: @prthrokz It's because a whole JSON is much bigger, it's even impossible to put it all here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that this seems to be a base64 encoded JPEG.  In most cases it would be better & easier to have your server send back the jpeg rather than JSON.

```
public ActionResult ShowImage() 
{
    var file = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UserUpload/asd.png");
    return File(file, "image/png", Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

[To see original source follow this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225485/asp-net-mvc3-image-loading-through-controller)

Answer (score 3):

Troubleshooting advice:

If you are unable to put the whole string, you may want to make it smaller to isolate the error.

Try removing a a block characters at a time (I would use a binary left/right half experimentation method) until it stops breaking.  Then look closer at the bad half.  If you can get the bad half small enough and are unable to see the error, please post it.

I am guessing the column given by the error isn't counted the same way that you are counting them.