# Pass image from controller and display in a view using ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I guess it's something very straight forward but I can't find out how to do it. In my controller I have:

```
 public ViewResult ShowForm()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = Resources.ApplicationTitle;
            ViewBag.LabelStatus = Resources.Status;
            //Logo
            ViewBag.Logo =@"C:\Images\Logo.png";
            return View("ShowForm");
        }
```

And in my view I try this:

```
<div id="drawForm">
<img src="@ViewBag.Logo" alt="Logo" />    
</div>
```

However when I run this I just get the "Logo" text.

Comment: So, is it during the page load or some on demand request to server ?

Comment: The image most probably will be kept on a Server, but the page content should be collected from the database before the page is loaded so I guess it is during page load.

Comment: It's a form with images that someone has already created and I just have to redraw it when the user asks for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Server.MapPath` to get the correct path of the image. Suppose your images folder is inside the `Content` folder that is normally included in an MVC project. You can do something like this:

```
public ViewResult ShowForm()
{
    //Logo
    ViewBag.Logo = Server.MapPath("~") + @"Content\Images\Logo.png";
    return View("ShowForm");
}
```

And you don't have to change the code in your view.

Comment: I see. Was expecting something a bit easier but guess it is what it is. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. That's the easiest way of doing it, IMO, and solves your sort of problem generally. But there is a much better way of doing it that involves a bit of setup, using image resizer tools. Tools that will make sure your images are served in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
ViewBag.Logo = Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Logo.png");
```

Comment: I share your codes on my blog: http://zinzinzibidi.com/blog/genel/mvc_ile_ozellestirilmis_sayfa_paylasim_gorseli_olusturmak

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 4):

You need a ImageController to render that.

See this:

[ASP.NET MVC3: Image loading through controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225485/asp-net-mvc3-image-loading-through-controller)

and this:
[Can an ASP.NET MVC controller return an Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186062/can-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-return-an-image)

once you have a controller you can render as follows:

```
public class ImageController{

public ActionResult ShowImage(string path) 
{

    return File(path);
}

}
```

in your views:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Render","Image", new {id =1  // or path })" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult ShowForm()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = Resources.ApplicationTitle;
            ViewBag.LabelStatus = Resources.Status;
            //Logo
           byte[] imgbytes =  File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Images\Logo.png");
           return File(imgbytes , "image/png");
        }

<div id="drawForm">
<img src="controllerName/ShowForm" alt="Logo" />    
</div>
```