# Addressing an images in View with its local path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How to display this image in an ASP.NET MVC project?

I've tried this, but it wouldn't work:

```
<img src="C:\BBBB\1.png" />
```

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: don't use a full path like that, just use a relative path.

Comment: @safetyOtter, that wouldn't work. My project is deployed into IIS by virtual directory. How to access to that path then?

Comment: Is that a path on the server or in the client directory?

Comment: This is not common way to address files on Server! Use `Server.MapPath("~/directory/filename")` where `~` stands for website root to access its **Local Address** on Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to this to display payroll stubs. I didn't want them accessible from within wwwroot.

See this article for serving an image from an mvc action.

[ASP.NET MVC3: Image loading through controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225485/asp-net-mvc3-image-loading-through-controller)

```
public ActionResult ShowImage(id) 
{
    var file = @"C:\BBB\"+id;
    var ext = file.Split('.').Last();
    return File(file, "image/"+ext, Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

Call it like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ShowImage",new { id="1.png" })" alt="1.png"/>
```

For a loop, you could do something like this in your existing view:

```
 for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) {
    @Html.Partial("ShowIfExists", new {id=i.ToString()+".png" })
 }
```

Create a new Razor View called _ShowIfExists.cshtml

```
 <img src="@Url.Action("ShowImage",new { id=Model })" alt="1.png"/>
```

And add a corresponding action:

```
public ActionResult ShowIfExists(id)
    if ( System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\BBB\"+id) )
        return PartialView("_ShowIfExists",null,id);
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: I'm in fact trying to display images in loop 1..2...png and to check if it exists. How may I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The image tag's src needs to point to where the image resides on a web server.

```
<img src="http://myserver.com/myimage.png" />
```

Comment: If the server is IIS, does this `http://myserver.com/` refers to `inetpub\wwwroot` ?

Comment: It could, but it might not even be your server. You could be pulling images from a content site (photobucket, flickr, etc.)

Comment: But, here I'm generating dynamically these photos!

Comment: Then the path is going to depend on where you put the image, if there is a virtual directory for that path, and if you are generating the image and pushing directly without storing it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference images with relative address like this: `../images/1.png`.

check this tutorial to start: [W3schools Html Tutorial/img Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on displaying a local image, you should include the protocol, which in this case is file://:

```
<img src="file://C:/BBBB/1.png" />
```

This is not a good idea for real projects tho.