# How to render image from kendo fileupload

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, upload, kendo-ui

I have a image tag

```
<div class="fielddiv-overflow">
    <img id="imglogo" src="#" alt="" height="45" width="65" />
</div>
```

and i am using kendo upload

```
<div class="labeldiv">
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files")
        .Multiple(false)
        .ShowFileList(false)
        .TemplateId("fileTemplate")
        .Async(a=>a .AutoUpload(true))
        .Files(files => files.Add().Extension(".img"))
         )
        @* <form method="post" action='@Url.Action("Save")'>
        </form>*@
    </div>
```

how to get image that is uploaded from kendo upload to image source

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried a lot for this can u plz suggest me ,i did google also but i dint get it.please help me

Answer (score 2):

How would you display image from the server which you do not know the name of? Similar question covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027970/image-handler-on-mvc). Once you upload is [completed](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/upload#events-complete) created an img tag that points to that image handler.