# how to access a resource that is not part of the project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to mvc3 and what I'm trying to do is show in a view the images that are saved in the file system under C:\temp

In my project I defined a resource, photo_url -> C:\temp, 
I pass to the view through ViewData, at the end I can get the complete and correct path of the file I want to display, example ... src = "C:\temp\img.jpg" ... but I get the error "Not allowed to load local resource:"

`src="@Url.Content(ViewData["path_photo"] + "\\" + item.link_photo)`

By putting the photos inside the project, for example in ..\..\content\photo, I can visualize them, but saving them outside the project I can't access them.
Help!
Thank you.

Comment: Are the images you're trying to show in C:\temp on the web server or on the browser's local hard drive? I'm assuming the image you're trying to show is on the web server, but src="C:\temp\img.jpg" in the HTML on the browser is trying to look on the browser's computer. You'll need to either make the images on the web server available via an endpoint, or - you can build an image handler where the web server reads the file from C:\temp and then streams the bits down to the browser. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027970/image-handler-on-mvc

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I work locally, I launch my application via visual studio in debug